# How to pass attribute name as a secondary parameter through link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

IN my application Controller

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:search])
    @feed_entries = @search.page(params[:page])
    @app_keys = AppKey.all
  end

  def update
    @feed_article = FeedEntry.find(params[:id])
    @feed_article.toggle!(@saad)
    redirect_to feed_entries_path
  end
end
```

And in my Views/feed_entries/index.html.erb

```
<div id="content">
<%= paginate @feed_entries, :theme => 'twitter-bootstrap'%>
<p><%= render(@feed_entries) || 'There is no Feeds'%><p>
<%= paginate @feed_entries, :theme => 'twitter-bootstrap'%>
</div>
```

And in _feed_entry.html.erb partial.

```
<%= link_to "Make UnStar |", feed_entry_path(:id => feed_entry.id, @saad => :is_to_read), method: :put %> <%= link_to feed_entry.name, feed_entry.url %>
```

But the above code is not working, I just want to pass attribute name (`:is_to_read`) as a secondary parameter through `link_to` into the controller's update action.

`:is_to_read is boolean` attribute of feedentries table.

Please someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is a pair of name and value. So it should be: :saad => ... and not @saad =>
Further you need to call the is_to_read attribute on the object. So:

```
<%= link_to "Make UnStar |", feed_entry_path(:id => feed_entry.id, :saad => @feedentry.is_to_read), method: :put %>
```